# If I wanted to change $_GET to $_POST in this code What would I do?

Tags: php

I can't seem to figure out how to post this instead of using get, I've found that you have to use a form but that's about it.
If anyone is willing to provide an answer that'd be awesome!
Thank you!!!!
.............................................................................................................................................................

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
<title>Portfolio Max</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css">
</head>
<body>

  <div class= "header">
    <h1 id= "textinheader">Portfolio</h1></div>
    <div class= "portfolio text"> </div>


    <div class="menu">
        <a href="?page=1">pagina 1</a>
        <a href="?page=2">pagina2</a>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="dropbutton">Meer
            <i class="down"></i>
          </button>
          <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="?page=3">pagina 3</a>
            <a href="?page=4">pagina 4</a>
            <a href="?page=5">pagina 5</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


    <?php  echo date("Y/M/D h:i:sa");?>

    </div>


   <?php 

   /*
   if( $_GET ['page'] == '1')
   include 'page1.php'; 
   else 
   include 'page2.php'; 
   */
  if (! isset($_GET ['page'])) 
  $_GET = array_merge( $_GET, array('page'=>1));

  include 'page'.$_GET ['page'].'.php';



   ?>

    </div>

 </body>
</html>c
```

Comment: `POST` your data instead of `GET` it, a good point to start from is : [HTML Forms](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp) , and [how to deal with forms in php](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php)

Comment: If you pass variables in the URL it's always a GET-request. I don't know why you want to do pagination via POST but then you have to use a form with post or JavaScript.

Comment: It's unlogical to change a page loading script from $_GET to $_POST

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/t5r16qoe/

```
<form id="formId" action="dataPost.php" title="" method="post">
    <div><label class="title">Name</label><input type="text" id="name" name="name" ></div>
<div><label class="title">Age</label><input type="text" id="age2" name="age" ></div>
<div><input type="submit" id="submitButton"  name="submitButton" value="Submit"></div>
</form>
```

in JS:

```
$("#formId").submit(function(event) {

  event.preventDefault();

    var $form = $( this ),
      url = $form.attr( 'action' );

  var posting = $.post( url, { name: $('#name').val(), age: $('#age').val() } );


  posting.done(function( data ) {
    alert('Saved!');
  });
});
```

in dataPost.php you can get the posted value like

```
echo $_POST['name'];
echo $_POST['age'];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't in php, if you are sending data via url parameters, the only way to retrieve this data from the url is via `GET`. you can read more on `GET` [here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php.). you will have to use `GET` to retrieve the page number from the `page` parameter. you can try javascript, get the values of the url and use `POST` to send the value to another `.php file`. From your code I assume this is for pagination, why do you need to `$_POST` rather than `$_GET`

Answer (score 0):

some pseudo code.

```
$("a").click(function){
var  query_string=$(this).attr("href");
//Iam lazy to write query string parser. Google or write yourself.
var obj = querystring_parser_to_key_value(query_string);
$form = $('<form method="POST" action=""></form>');
$.each( obj, function( key, value ) {
  $form.append('<input type="hidden" name="'+key+'" value="'+value+'">');
});
  $form.submit();
});
```